# If(picturebox.Right == panel.Right) not working but if(picturebox.Left == panel.Left) works

Tags: c#, visual-studio, collision-detection, picturebox, pong

I'm not sure why but anytime I'm working with collision it seems like that everything goes well for the top and left properties of a control, but for the right and bottom properties not so much. I'm not sure if its because they are read only properties or not, but someone please help.

heres the code

playground(panel) class

```
    namespace final_pong_game_phase_3
{
class PlayGround
{
    public Panel Panel;
    Size PlayGroundSize;
    public int Top;
    public int Bottom;
    public int Right;
    public int Left;
    public PlayGround(Panel panel,Size size, Point location)
    {
        this.Panel = panel;
        this.PlayGroundSize = size;
        this.Panel.Size = this.PlayGroundSize;
        this.Panel.BackColor = Color.Black;
        this.Panel.Location = location;
        this.Panel.SendToBack();

        this.Top = panel.Top;
        this.Bottom = panel.Bottom;
        this.Right = panel.Right;
        this.Left= panel.Left;
    }



}
}
```

Ball(picturebox) Class

```
    namespace final_pong_game_phase_3
  {
class Ball
{
    Size BallSize;
    Point Location;
    int TopSpeedInterval;
    int LeftSpeedInterval;
    PictureBox BallGraphic;
    public int Top;
    public int Left;
    public int Bottom;
    public int Right;

    public Ball(Point location, int topspeedinterval,int leftspeedinterval, Size ballsize, PictureBox ballgraphic)
    {
        this.Location = location;
        this.TopSpeedInterval = topspeedinterval;
        this.LeftSpeedInterval = leftspeedinterval;
        this.BallSize = ballsize;
        this.BallGraphic = ballgraphic;

        this.BallGraphic.Location = this.Location;
        this.BallGraphic.BackColor = Color.White;
        this.BallGraphic.Size = this.BallSize;
        this.BallGraphic.BringToFront();

        this.Top = BallGraphic.Top;
        this.Left = BallGraphic.Left;
        this.Bottom = ballgraphic.Bottom;

    } 

    public void start()
    {
        Top -= TopSpeedInterval;
        Left -= LeftSpeedInterval;

        BallGraphic.Top = Top;
        BallGraphic.Left = Left;
        Bottom = BallGraphic.Bottom;
        Right = BallGraphic.Right;


    } 

    public void SwitchTopDirection()
    {
        TopSpeedInterval *=-1; 

    } 

    public void SwitchLeftDirection()
    {
        LeftSpeedInterval *= -1;
    } 

    public void Hit()
    {
        TopSpeedInterval+= 5;
        LeftSpeedInterval+= 5;
    }
}
 }
```

GameWorld(controls and monitors the game everything in the method of the class happens every time the timer ticks) Class

```
    //ball to wall collision 
        if (playground.Top == ball.Top)
        {
            ball.SwitchTopDirection();
            Console.Beep(1000, 100);
        }

        if (playground.Left == ball.Left)
        {
            Console.Beep(1500, 700);
            MessageBox.Show("Player 2 Wins!!!");

        }

        if (playground.Right == ball.Right)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Player 2 Wins!!!");
        }

        if (ball.Bottom >= playground.Bottom)
        {
            ball.SwitchTopDirection();
            Console.Beep(1000, 100);
        }
```

Comment: You *probably* should care more about the Width and Height than the Right and Bottom, I'm guessing.

Comment: even if i change the right property to equal left + width it still does not work. Really it only works when i do <= rather than ==.

Comment: You should not test for equality but for `<=`  or  `>=`

Comment: Yea i did try tat before  and it worked but once the ball passess d wall the message box keeps popping  up

Comment: I see why you guys wanted me to use <= now and i see why it was not working because my ball was incrementing at 10 pixels so if it starts at 0 it can never equal 505 because 505 is not divisible by zero so ill just end up using the <= now or use a number that 505 is divisible to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would probably do the trick for you

```
if (Math.Abs(playground.Right - ball.Right)<=7)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Player 2 Wins!!!");
}
```

What we are doing in this code is that we are checking the range of +-7 of both Playground and Ball it collides.

Comment: Alright  thank i will try it but i think it will have similar  results  to using <=